# суммировать одинаковые элемента списка python

Tags: python, list, список

Дан список:

`s1 = [['REDHEA', 3], ['GADWAL', 1], ['SMEW', 4], ['GRESCA', 10], ['REDHEA', 3], ['GADWAL', 9], ['GRESCA', 15], ['COMEID', 6]]`

необходимо суммировать цифровые значения у одинаковых имен:

```
["COMEID", 6, "GADWAL", 10, "GRESCA", 25, "REDHEA", 6, "SMEW", 4]
```

после долгих мучений подсмотрел такой варинт:

```
 s2 = {}
for i in s1:
    if i[0] in s2:
        s[i[0]] += i[-1]
    else:
        s[i[0]] = i[-1]
```

создаю словарь, в него добавляю первый элемент вложенного списка, если первый элемент вложенного списка уже есть как ключ в словаре, суммирую значения ключа...
но мне выдает ошибку:

```
TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not str
```

не знаю как это победить, ведь на примере, который я опробовал, все работало:

```
a = [['a', 2], ['b', 3], ['c', 4], ['a', 5]]
s = {}
for i in a:
    if i[0] in s:
        s[i[0]] += i[1]
    else:
       s[i[0]] = i[1]
print(s)
```

может многоуважаемая публика подскажет как решить эту проблему, или подскажет другое решение?

Comment: У меня ваш код работает и на первом списке. Тот, который второй. А в первом вы создаёте словарь `s2`, а потом наполняете другую переменную с именем `s`. Внимательно проверьте что у вас `s`, `s1` и `s2`.

Comment: Странно, у меня второй код не работает на первом списке, интересно, с чем это может быть связано? PyCharm 21.3, версия Python - 3.10...

Comment: Вот сами [можете удостовериться](https://ideone.com/GqIbs3), что работает.

Comment: Удостоверился, чудеса и только) Огромнейшее спасибо за ответы!)

Answer (score 2):

Вот вам для общего развития вариант решения с pandas:

```
mport pandas as pd
s1 = [['REDHEA', 3], ['GADWAL', 1], ['SMEW', 4], ['GRESCA', 10], ['REDHEA', 3], ['GADWAL', 9], ['GRESCA', 15], ['COMEID', 6]]
res = pd.DataFrame(s1).groupby(0).sum().reset_index().squeeze().values.ravel().tolist()
```

res:

```
['COMEID', 6, 'GADWAL', 10, 'GRESCA', 25, 'REDHEA', 6, 'SMEW', 4]
```

Answer (score 1):

Существует такой подход к заполнению словаря.

```
s1 = [['REDHEA', 3], ['GADWAL', 1], ['SMEW', 4], ['GRESCA', 10], ['REDHEA', 3], ['GADWAL', 9], ['GRESCA', 15], ['COMEID', 6]]
d1 = {}
for name, value in s1:
    d1[name] = d1.get(name, 0) + value
s2 = list(sum(d1.items(), ()))
```